# How to combine numbers if their difference is smaller than 5 in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a vector and I want to combine numbers into groups if their difference is smaller than 5. Thanks for any help.

For example,

```
Mydata = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,24,25,26,27,28,35,36,37,38,39)
```

My intention is to have groups of data like this:

```
(1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14,15)
(24,25,26,27,28)
(35,36,37,38,39)
```

Comment: `groups <- cumsum(c(0,diff(Mydata) > 5))`

Comment: Building on Jaap's comment, try `split(x, cumsum(c(1L, diff(x)) > 5))`

Comment: @markus Thank you for your help. Could you explain why you use `1L` in the `cumsum` instead of `0`?

Comment: @YangYang That is a habit. `1L` returns an integer, instead of a double (`1`). Storing integers is memory  efficient. In your example it doesn't make a difference though, because the result of `diff` is of class numeric and `1L` will be coerced to numeric.

Comment: @markus Thanks a lot for your help. If so, I wonder what the `0` means in `cumsum(c(0,diff(Mydata) > 5))`? Thanks.

Comment: @Jaap Thank you. Could you explain what the `0` means in `cumsum(c(0,diff(Mydata) > 5))`? Thanks.

Comment: That's because `diff(Mydata) > 5` results in a vector that is one item shorter than `Mydata`, therefore you need to combine it with either `0` or `1` to get a vector that is of equal length as `Mydata`. Check the difference between `length(Mydata)` and `length(diff(Mydata) > 5)`.

Comment: @Jaap Thanks a lot for your help.